# Using default MonoTouch solutions yield build errors

Tags: ios, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

When I create a universal single-page application solution in MonoDevelop 3.0 the build fails because:

```
 {DIRECTORY}/iTEST/AppDelegate.cs(7,7): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `MonoTouch' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? (CS0246) (iTEST)
```

I looked in Preferences -> SDK locations -> and verified that I have the MonoTouch SDK installed. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had the experimental build feature enabled, which does not support ASP.NET or MonoTouch projects. This can be disabled via the Preferences->Build pane.

Comment: `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.9/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets` gives a bit more clue. Look at MonoDevelop menu, Preferences... Under Preferences (tree view) select **Build** and make sure **Compile project using MSBuild / XBuild" is **NOT** checked.

Answer (score 1):

Does the generated project has a reference to `monotouch.dll` ? If not then you'll need to add one manually.

I created a new *Universal*, *Single View Application* project using MonoDevelop 3.0 and it worked without issue (and the reference to `monotouch.dll` is present).

Comment: Yes monotouch is among the references

Comment: I reinstalled MonoTouch and I know have this error: Build failed. Runtime 'Mono 2.10.9' does not have the MSBuild '4.0' framework installed What could this mean?

Comment: It looks like this is not a MonoTouch project, but a new MonoTouch file/type added inside a *normal* .NET project. That would explain your last error **and** the first one. Start from scratch and make sure you create a new MonoTouch project.

Comment: Could this be due to the solution? The solution that I adding the new project to is one that originated in VS2010. How can I make the solution work on both OS X and Windows?

Comment: I'm pretty sure solutions are *vanilla* and identical to VS.NET (I commonly add stuff to/from them) but executable projects must be **Target framework: Mono for iPhone** (see project's options, Build, General).

Comment: It says "Mono for iPhone" and it is grayed out. Also if I make a brand new solution with a universal singe page application project it still gets that same error.

Comment: Grayed out is normal (and ok). Looks like it's time for a bug report -> http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: What would be the best way to do a complete removal of MonoDevelop? If I drag the .app file into trash it simply removes the program but not the settings. Note I don't want to remove Mono, only MonoDevelop. I think there is an issue with my installation and I would like do a full reinstall with an earlier version of MonoDevelop